# Python Script iGAN theano Error

Tags: python, image, image-processing, theano

I'm trying to use software called iGAN created by junyanz from Berkeley. https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~junyanz/projects/averageExplorer/

[iGAN - Github](https://github.com/junyanz/iGAN/blob/master/README.md)

I've installed the necessary dependencies but I seem to get stuck when I run the script. My goal is average a few thousand photos but first I need to get the script running.

```
mint@mint:~/iGAN > python iGAN_main.py
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Failed to import scipy.linalg.blas, and Theano flag blas.ldflags is empty. Falling back on slower implementations for dot(matrix, vector), dot(vector, matrix) and dot(vector, vector) (No module named scipy.linalg.blas)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iGAN_main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import constrained_opt
  File "/home/mint/iGAN/constrained_opt.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lib.rng import np_rng
  File "/home/mint/iGAN/lib/rng.py", line 2, in <module>
    from theano.sandbox.rng_mrg import MRG_RandomStreams as RandomStreams
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 71, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 58, in <module>
    from six import iteritems, integer_types, raise_from
ImportError: cannot import name raise_from
mint@mint:~/iGAN >
```

I'm a photographer by trade and tinker with code as a hobby. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try 'pip install --upgrade six' before running the code

Comment: Thanks! It sadly had no effect. The error is the same. `mint@mint:~/iGAN > sudo pip install --upgrade si
Downloading/unpacking si
  Downloading si-0.1.1-1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/si/setup.py) egg_info for package si
    
Installing collected packages: si
  Running setup.py install for si
    
Successfully installed si
Cleaning up...
mint@mint:~/iGAN > nano iGAN_main.py 
mint@mint:~/iGAN > python  iGAN_main.py 
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected !...`